# html5 speech input languages

Tags: html

Hello i'm doing some research on speech to text technologies and i'm wondering which spoken languages are suported by the speech input object that comes with html5.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None - it's only a hook into a speech recognition system. It is not the system itself.